# Netbeans Javadoc auto-displaying

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, javadoc

I am working on an xml file inside of Netbeans and something changed in my settings where when I open up a bracket, it turns the bracket red and displays the Javadoc in addition to the code-completion tool.

[image]

I like the code-completion but not the javadoc.  Does someone know how to turn it off the Javadoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer:

In Netbeans, go Tools -> Options -> Code Completion -> uncheck "Auto Popup Documentation Window"

I'm still not sure what keyboard shortcut I hit to enable it in the first place, but this turned it off.